# Checking proper English sentences of user's input with grammar using C++

Tags: c++, grammar

> Write a program that checks if a sentence is correct according to the
>   “English” grammar in §6.4.1. Assume that every sentence is terminated
>   by a full stop (.) surrounded by whitespace. For example, birds fly
>   but the fish swim . is a sentence, but birds fly but the fish swim
>   (terminating dot missing) and birds fly but the fish swim. (no space
>   before dot) are not. For each sentence entered, the program should
>   simply respond “OK” or “not OK.” Hint: Don’t bother with tokens; just
>   read into a string using >>.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string str;

void putback(string s) {
    str = s;
}

string verb() {
    if (str == "rules" || str == "fly" || str == "swim") {
        return str + ' ';
    }
    else 
        return "";
}

string noun() {
    if (str == "birds" || str == "fish" || str == "C++") {
        return str + ' ';
    }
    else 
        return "";
}

string article() {
    if (str == "the") {
        string temp = str;
        cin >> str;
        return temp + ' ';
    }
    else 
        return "";
}

string conjunction() {
    if (str == "and" || str == "or" || str == "but") {
        return str + ' ';
    }
    else 
        return "";
}

string l;
string sentence() {
    l += article();
    if (noun() == "") {
        cerr << "NOT OK";
        return "";
    }
    else {
        l += noun();
        cin >> str;
        string temp = verb();
        if (temp == "") {
            cerr << "NOT OK";
            return "";
        }
        else {
            l += temp;
            cin >> str;
            if (str == "") {
                cerr << "NOT OK";
                return " ";
            }
            else if (str == ".") {
                l += ".";
                return l;
            }
            else {
                if(conjunction() == "") {
                    cerr << "NOT OK";
                }
                else {
                    l += str + ' ';
                    cin >> str;
                }
                return sentence();
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() 
try 
{
    string sen = " ";
    while (cin) {
        cin >> str;
        sen = sentence();
        if (str == ".") {
            cout << sen << '\n';
        }
    }
    //keep_window_open();
}
catch (exception& e) 
{
    cerr << "error: " << e.what() << '\n';
    //keep_window_open();
    return 1;
}
catch (...) 
{
    cerr << "Oops: unknown exception!\n";
    //keep_window_open();
    return 2;
}
```

> ```
> The Grammar:
> Sentence:
>           Noun Verb                                   // e.g., C++ rules
>           Article Noun Verb
>           Sentence Conjunction Sentence   // e.g., Birds fly but fish swim
> Conjunction:
>           "and"
>           "or"
>           "but"
> Article:
>           "the"
> Noun:
>           "birds"
>           "fish"
>           "C++"
> Verb:
>           "rules"
>           "fly"
>           "swim"
> ```

This is perfectly working code. Is there anything I can improve on for my code? Do you think using global variables in this case is okay? Even for whether I have proper variable names is worth commenting. This question is from [this webpage](http://apprize.info/c/principles/6.html), exercise 6 at the very bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You could learn how to use bison. It designed specifically for this.

Boiler plate for flex/bison project:

#### Eng.l

```
%option c++

%{
#define IN_EXPR_LEXER
#include "EngYac.hpp"
%}

SpaceChar     [ \t]
Space         {SpaceChar}+
SpaceTerm     {SpaceChar}|<<EOF>>
FullStop      {SpaceChar}\.{SpaceTerm}

%%

and                     {return yy::parser::token::Conjunction;}
or                      {return yy::parser::token::Conjunction;}
but                     {return yy::parser::token::Conjunction;}

the                     {return yy::parser::token::Article;}

birds                   {return yy::parser::token::Noun;}
fish                    {return yy::parser::token::Noun;}
C\+\+                   {return yy::parser::token::Noun;}

rules                   {return yy::parser::token::Verb;}
fly                     {return yy::parser::token::Verb;}
swim                    {return yy::parser::token::Verb;}

{FullStop}              {return yy::parser::token::FullStop;}

{Space}                 {/*Ignore*/}
.                       {std::cerr << "Error unknown character\n";}

%%

int yyFlexLexer::yywrap(void)
{
    return 1;
}


int yylex(int* /*type*/, yyFlexLexer& lexer)
{
    return lexer.yylex();
}
```

### Eng.y

```
%{
    #ifndef IN_EXPR_LEXER
    #include <FlexLexer.h>
    #endif
    int yylex(int* type, yyFlexLexer& lexer);
%}
%skeleton "lalr1.cc"
%defines
%parse-param {yyFlexLexer& lexer}
%lex-param   {yyFlexLexer& lexer}

%token      Noun
%token      Verb
%token      Article
%token      Conjunction
%token      FullStop

%%
Input:      Sentence FullStop    

Sentence:   Noun Verb
        |   Article Noun Verb
        |   Sentence Conjunction Sentence


%%

void yy::parser::error(yy::location const&, std::string const& msg)
{
    std::cerr << "Error: " << msg << "\n";
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <FlexLexer.h>
#include "EngYac.hpp"

int main()
{
    yyFlexLexer     lexer(&std::cin, &std::cout);
    yy::parser      parser(lexer);

    std::cout << (parser.parse() ? "FAIL" : "OK") << "\n";
}
```

### Makefile

```
FLEX_SRC    = $(wildcard *.l)
BISON_SRC   = $(wildcard *.y)
FLEX_CPP    = $(patsubst %.l, %Lex.cpp, $(FLEX_SRC))
BISON_CPP   = $(patsubst %.y, %Yac.cpp, $(BISON_SRC))

SRC         = $(filter-out $(BISON_CPP), $(filter-out $(FLEX_CPP), $(wildcard *.cpp))) $(FLEX_CPP) $(BISON_CPP)
OBJ         = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRC))


eng:       $(OBJ)
    g++ -o eng -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror $(OBJ)

clean:
    rm EngLex.cpp EngYac.cpp EngYac.hpp location.hh position.hh stack.hh $(OBJ) expr


$(OBJ): $(FLEX_CPP) $(BISON_CPP)

%Lex.cpp:       %.l
    flex -o $*Lex.cpp $^

%Yac.cpp:       %.y
    bison -o $*Yac.cpp $^
```

Usage:

```
> make
> echo "birds rules but fish swim." | ./eng

OK
> echo "A test of English." | ./eng 
A test of English
Error: syntax error
FAIL
```

Comment: What about the "no dot before the spaces" part from the task?

Comment: @RolandIllig: The dot surrounded by space is to allow for easy parsing with `operator>>`. Its easy to do if we want to be perfect.

Comment: @RolandIllig: But I was bored. So updated.

Comment: Thanks. I was just curious how you would implement it, since it is a non-trivial problem with many solutions that work _almost always_. :)

Comment: @RolandIllig I dislike the solution because it does not reflect real life usage. In real sentences punctuation is usually not separated from the word by a space. So I personally think the specification is wrong. But we code to the specifications. :-)